# Cloudflare: Override url to different path

Tags: dns, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, http-proxy

I have Cloudflare set up to CNAME `www.foo.com` to `www.bar.com`. The icon in the console shows that DNS and HTTP proxy are enabled. When I visit `www.foo.com`, I see the content for `www.bar.com`.

I'd like it so that when Cloudflare receives urls of the form `www.foo.com/ORIGINAL_PATH` it proxies the request to `www.bar.com/x/y/z/ORIGINAL_PATH`. I want Cloudflare to proxy the request - not to redirect it.

Is there a Page Rule(s) which could help with this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without cooperation from the web server as well. The server would be expecting a request to bar.com when it actually sees foo.com. I'm not positive, though. If it were possible, it seems like a security risk as I could buy myawesomeemailservice.com and proxy traffic to gmail.com. I can't imagine that being technically possible.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I would like to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page Rule's Request Transform and Resolve Override for this. You'll need to create both on the Cloudflare dashboard

On Cloudflare dashboard go to Rules -> Transform Rules and create a new url rewrite rule:

- When hostname `equals` [www.bar.com](http://www.bar.com)
- Static Rewrite path to `/x/y/z/`

On the Cloudflare Dashboard go to Rules -> Page Rules, and create a new rule:

- If the URL matches: [www.foo.com/](http://www.foo.com/)*
- Setting: Resolve Override | Value: [www.bar.com](http://www.bar.com)
- Setting: Host Header Override | Value: [www.foo.com](http://www.foo.com)

See these links for more info:

- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206190798-Using-Resolve-Override-in-Page-Rules.
- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/reverse-proxy-based-on-a-path/143610

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think it can be done with Page Rules alone, you can achieve that with Cloudflare Workers.

1. Open the source domain page in Cloudflare dashboard.
2. Go to the `Workers` tab.
3. `Manage Workers` `->` `Create a Worker`
4. Add the code. You can hardcode the path or you can make it dynamic as below to allow adding multiple redirecting paths.

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

/**
 * Respond to the request
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  const { pathname } = url

  const targetUrl = `https://www.target-domain.com/x/y/z${pathname}`
  
  return fetch(targetUrl)
}
```

5. Go back to the `Workers` tab of your source domain `->` `Add route`. Set Route to `www.source-domain.com/ORIGINAL_PATH`. Select the worker you created in step 4 and `Save`.
6. Give it a moment to digest the new settings and confirm the redirect works.